# How can I find the mass of a thin wire in the shape of a helix?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the mass of a thin wire in the shape of a helix given by $\overrightarrow {r}(t)=\langle \cos t,\sin t, t\rangle$ for $0\le t\le6\pi$ with density of $z$ at the point $(x,y,z)$ on the wire (curve)?

Can you all provide me with a hint as to how I should get started with this one?

I know that:

$$M=\int^{x_1}_{x_0}\int^{y_1}_{y_0}\int^{z_1}_{z_0}\sigma(x,y,z)\;dz\;dy\;dx$$

Does this mean that:

$$M=\int^{6\pi}_{0}\int^{6\pi}_{0}\int^{6\pi}_{0}z\;dz\;dy\;dx$$

Comment: @CarlosMendoza well I know mass it typically defined as $M=\iint_D \rho (x,y)\;dA$ but I don't know how to apply that for a position vector?

Comment: I know that you are new ;) in the platform but people is usually more willing to collaborate when they see that this is not just a homework question without any proof of effort. I suggest you to put what do you know (as that integral)  and what you have tried or at least what are your thoughts or ideas about the solution.

Comment: @CarlosMendoza thanks for the guidance, I'll modify my post to include my horrible attempt at solving this!

Comment: @CarlosMendoza OK I edited my post, hopefully you can review and now provide me with some tips as to if I'm on the right path or not

Comment: The answer must depend on the radius of the wire. I suspect that we are not told the density but rather the "linear density" (not sure what the right term is) at each point on the wire.

Comment: My comments were intended mainly for helping you to improve your question so it can get more attention from the community, look that you get now a comment regarding the solution! Although I am not an expert in calculus, I think that you should integrate over the helix, not over a cube (you have all the integral limits constant). Thus, the limits for $x$ and $y$ should be from $0$ to $cos(z)$ and $sin(z)$, respectively. The last integral should be respect to $z$ and the limits are the ones that you already have.

Comment: @littleO how can I find the radius of the wire with the given information?

Comment: @CarlosMendoza thank you for the forum etiquette assistance!  I also appreciate your guidance in the problem I'm solving.  :-)  I will remember all of this for the future

Comment: You need to evaluate the integral $$\int_a^b \sigma(\mathbf r(t))\, \|\mathbf r'(t)\|\,dt$$

Comment: We can't find the radius of the wire, of course; we're told that the wire is "thin" but we aren't told how thin.  We must think carefully about what "density" means in this problem.  Usually density means mass per unit volume.  In this problem, however, I suspect that "density" means mass per unit length.  So chop up the wire into tiny pieces, compute the mass of each tiny piece (multiplying density by the tiny length) and then add up all the little masses to get the total mass.  In other words, do a line integral.

Comment: I am glad you now have two answers! Finally, you should vote up and/or accept an answer if it's useful and/or effectively answer your question. It is also a good practice to comment an answer to politely asking for clarification if you don't understand some part of the answer. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can find more information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, given the density $\rho (x,y,z)$ at each point of a curve $C$, the mass of $C$ is given by the line integral (of the first kind)

$$\int \limits _C \rho (x,y,z) \Bbb d C .$$

If your curve is parametrized by $[a,b] \ni t \mapsto \big( x(t), y(t), z(t) \big) \in \Bbb R ^3$, then the above formula means

$$\int \limits _a ^b \rho \big( x(t), y(t), z(t) \big) \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 + z'(t)^2} \Bbb d t .$$

In your concrete case $\rho \big( x(t), y(t), z(t) \big) = z(t) = t$, so the mass is

$$\int \limits _0 ^{6 \pi} t \sqrt {(-\sin t)^2 + (\cos t)^2 + 1^2} \Bbb d t = \int \limits _0 ^{6 \pi} t \sqrt 2 \Bbb d t = 18 \pi^2 \sqrt 2 .$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf r(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ .

As @littleO says, you have to evaluate a line integral, that is $$\int_C \sigma(x,y,z)\,ds=\int_a^b\sigma(x(t),y(t),z(t))\, \sqrt {[x'(t)]^2+[y'(t)]^2+[z'(t)]^2}\,dt$$ See my comment also.